# A holomorphic function in a unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

my question is the following: Let $f$ be a holomorphic function from the unit disc to the unit disc. Also, $f(w) = f(-w) = 0$ for some $w \in \mathbb{D}$. Show that $|f(0)| \le |w|^2$. Unfortunately, I do not know even how to start. Can you provide me some hints please?

PS: I am not looking forward to a complete solution.

Comment: Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true [...], it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts.  – From [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969).

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1896349/42969

Comment: Thanks @MartinR.